# Transforming the PDE $c^2 \frac{{\partial}^2y}{\partial x^2} = \frac{{\partial}^2y}{\partial t^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If we have the PDE $ c^2 \frac{{\partial}^2y}{\partial x^2} = \frac{{\partial}^2y}{\partial t^2}$

Make the transformation $ y= z + a(x/L)sin(\omega t) $ to the above PDE to formulate a new PDE.

How would we do this?

So far I have found that $\frac{{\partial}^2y}{\partial x^2} = \frac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial x^2}$.

But I am confused as to how to find $\frac{{\partial}^2z}{\partial t^2}$.

Comment: I assume you have attempted to replace $y$ by its expression in the PDE. Show where you are blocked.

Comment: $z$ is a constant, thus its first derivative is already $0$.